# How to distinguish identically named VueJS + WebPack modules in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, namespaces, google-chrome-devtools, vue-cli

I am developing an application with `VueJS` bundled by `WebPack 4`.  It has a number of *CRUD* modules distinguished by a directory for each one, but with same named files in each. So....

```
components
  ╠═ Person
  ║   ╠═ index.js
  ║   ╠═ Create.vue
  ║   ╠═ Update.vue
  ║   ╠═ Retrieve.vue
  ║   ╚═ Delete.vue
  ╠═ Tool
  ║   ╠═ index.js
  ║   ╠═ Create.vue
  ║   ╠═ Update.vue
  ║   ╠═ Retrieve.vue
  ║   ╚═ Delete.vue
  ╚═ Zone
      ╠═ index.js
      ╠═ Create.vue
      ╠═ Update.vue
      ╠═ Retrieve.vue
      ╚═ Delete.vue
```

My problem is that I can find only one of each of `Create.vue, Update.vue, Retrieve.vue, Delete.vue` when I go to debug with `Chrome Dev Tools`.

If I put a `console.log()` in `Tool/Update.vue` I can see the logged message in the Chrome console, but when I click on the source code reference (on the right hand side), the code shown is from `Person/Update.vue`.

I can see no way at all to set a breakpoint in the correct module.

Do I have to refactor my whole project to always use distinct names?
Is there a WebPack setting to enforce name spacing?

As a work around I temporarily rename `Tool/Update.vue` to `Tool/dbgUpdate.vue`, fix all references to it and then I can find it and debug it.

**Update: 2018-11-30**

I followed Nandiin Bao's [entirely valid suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53550172/1544075) but I do not get the same result, Instead I get:

[image]

Not one of those files *pretty prints* to anything resembling the source code.

The only files that **do** look like the source code are found here:

[image]

But there is exactly one of each, so I am back to the same problem.

My webpack configuration is the unaltered default generated by `vue-cli 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can access intermediate files with human readable file hierarchy under `Page` sub tab under `Source` tab of the devtool.

[image]

Comment: I am very grateful for your correct answer based on what I first explained, but as you will see from the update the problem goes deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72009811/109351:

This worked for me when using `vue-cli-service serve`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2978#issuecomment-577364101

In vue.config.js:

```
let path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      // See available sourcemaps:
      // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool
      config.devtool = 'eval-source-map'
      // console.log(`NOTICE: vue.config.js directive: ${config.devtool}`)

      config.output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate = info => {
        let resPath = path.normalize(info.resourcePath)
        let isVue = resPath.match(/\.vue$/)
        let isGenerated = info.allLoaders

        let generated = `webpack-generated:///${resPath}?${info.hash}`
        let vuesource = `vue-source:///${resPath}`

        return isVue && isGenerated ? generated : vuesource
      }

      config.output.devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate =
        'webpack:///[resource-path]?[hash]'
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Wow!  I had entirely forgotten I was ever trying to do that!  I've no way of testing if that would work for me.  Would it be bad practice to mark it as correct?

Comment: I wonder how this issue still exists after 3.5 years :-/