# How to distinguish files which have the same name but in different sub-folders in sourcemap?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

In my VUE project, there are several templates which have the same filename but located in different source sub-folders. I'm using webpack 3.12 to build it, and the devtool set to 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'.

After I run webpack-dev-server 2.11.1 to debug it, all template source files are put into the root folder 'webpack://' of the browser's sourcemap, so ONLY one of these files can exist, others are lost, I can't debug them.

Is there a way to make these files co-existing in the sourcemap?

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
],
context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
      config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{
        from: /.*/,
        to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html')
      }, ],
    },
    hot: true,
    contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay ?
      {
        warnings: false,
        errors: true
      } :
      false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My advice is to use `inline-source-map` during the development.

Comment: That doesn't help, the problem still remains.

Comment: There should be (among the others) 2 folders under the `webpack://` namespace - one is called `.` and the other is `src`. The Vue single-file components reside in the `src` folder while the pure/normal JavaScript files reside in the `.`. There will be also a `node_modules` folder under the `webpack://`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53549873/109351 ?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I changed 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' to 'module-eval-source-map', the relative path of source files are kept.

I've read the official document of devtool, it says "it doesn't have column mappings, it only maps line numbers." if "cheap" mode used, I don't understand why the relative path is discarded.

> eval-cheap-source-map - Similar to eval-source-map, each module is executed with eval(). It is "cheap" because it doesn't have column
> mappings, it only maps line numbers. It ignores SourceMaps from
> Loaders and only display transpiled code similar to the eval devtool.
>
> eval-cheap-module-source-map - Similar to eval-cheap-source-map, however, in this case Source Maps from Loaders are processed for
> better results. However Loader Source Maps are simplified to a single
> mapping per line.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when using `vue-cli-service serve`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2978#issuecomment-577364101

In vue.config.js:

```
let path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      // See available sourcemaps:
      // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool
      config.devtool = 'eval-source-map'
      // console.log(`NOTICE: vue.config.js directive: ${config.devtool}`)

      config.output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate = info => {
        let resPath = path.normalize(info.resourcePath)
        let isVue = resPath.match(/\.vue$/)
        let isGenerated = info.allLoaders

        let generated = `webpack-generated:///${resPath}?${info.hash}`
        let vuesource = `vue-source:///${resPath}`

        return isVue && isGenerated ? generated : vuesource
      }

      config.output.devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate =
        'webpack:///[resource-path]?[hash]'
    }
  },
}
```